# How to populate elements for leap year

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a really simple question but can't seem to wrap my head around it or think of something that will work. All I want to do is populate a array of 100 elements to store leap year. So I will be starting from the year 1804 and of course will be adding 4 years since a leap year is every 4 years. The code is really small.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int month = 0;
int day = 0;
int year = 0;
int leapyear[100];

cout << "Please enter a date of birth in the format MMDDYYYY, month,day,and year should be seperate, so press enter after entering the numbers: ";
cin >> month;
cin >> day;
cin >> year;

int leapyear = 1804;

for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
{
    leapyear [i] + 4;  //I know this can not be correct, what can I do here?  
}
for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
{
    cout << leapyear[i];
}
```

Comment: There are special rules for century years.

Comment: Does this even compile? You have two variables with the same name (`leapyear`) declared in the same scope

Comment: Leap years are not "every 4 years". The wikipedia article has the explanation and pseudo-code.

Comment: What is the purpose of the date of birth? What does that have to do with filling in an array of leap years?

Comment: Your first loop should contain something like `leapyear[i] = <something>;`

Comment: Also both your loops only access 99 elements of the array instead of all 100

Comment: The reason there is a month and day as well is because I plan on doing a exception program where is the user enters a invalid day or month it will have them retry it. The program does compile and run, however is just gives out random junk from the RAM.

Comment: Why do you need a list of all leap years for that? After they enter a year, just use an `if` statement to check if it's a leap year. Read the Wikipedia page.

Comment: You can random junk because you never assign anything to the `leapyear` array. `leapyear[i] + 4` doesn't do anything.

Comment: @SergioGutierrez It doens't compile. I tried compiling it and got this: `error: redefinition of 'leapyear' with a different type: 'int' vs 'int [100]'`

Comment: @Barmar oh man, for some reason I have not encountered that error, I am just getting random junk and I did realize that the leapyear[i] + 4 does not do anything. That is what I am trying to figure out, I am trying the if statement like you said and reading the Wikipedia page. I have created a for loop for the initiation of the leap year array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign to the `leapyear` array. Something like this:

```
for (int i = 0, curyear = 1904; i < 100; i++, curyear += 4) {
    // skip century years, unless divisible by 400
    if (curyear % 100 == 0 && curyear % 400 != 0) {
        continue;
    }
    leapyear[i] = curyear;
}
```